# Mobile hybrid app - deployment to android & ios

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, hybrid

I am developing a hybrid app in HTML5/CSS/JS. How do I deploy this to Android and iOS?
Do I need to use frameworks such as Phonegap or others?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need `Phonegap` for filling the gap between `web app` and `mobile app` and some configuration for both platform

Comment: Are there any options other than phonegap? Just trying to evaluate the best one. And even using phonegap, how do we do it?

Comment: For this you should take a deep dive into `PhoneGap` official documentation for startup take a look here : http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/07/25/tips-for-developing-apps-with-pg/

Comment: So, even using phonegap, is there a different process for deploying to both android and ios or is it that the work has to be done once for deploying to both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach can be to have a web view pointing to your starting html page on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [INTEL XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk) to create hybrid apps. Just download and create new project ,copy paste your html code to the www folder and add free certificate and build the application by click start building in build tab.